# Overlay a field on an image using Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, css

I'd like to display a calculated value inside a circle image on a Visualforce page. Have looked thru CSS background properties, image tags but not finding a way to do this. Are there a listing of custom components that would provide this?

This is what I'd like to display on the page:

[image]

The Visualforce page where I'd like to place Account_Summary__c.Average_Risk_Score__c over the circular image.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="out">    
<b><apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:black" value="Average Risk Score"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; <apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:14px;color:blue" value="{!Account_Summary__c.Average_Risk_Score__c}"/> </b>                                         
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

not clear if what you want is a circle around your field value, or liteally want  your text field value over an image, both are basic CSS related.

for example:

```
<div class="circle">A Number</div>

<style>
.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000
}

</style>
```

will basically put your field value in a circle.

if you want to set a background image to your field, again, with css you just need to scope your background-image accordingly and center your text.

there are plenty of resources online explaining how to achieve this.

Comment: Either case is what I'm looking for. I have looked online which is why I'm asking for more insight. Can you suggest other areas to look at?

Comment: You should be able to do so with the above, you have not posted what you have attempted. It looks like you want someone to provide you the exact code on how to achieve this. If you are unable to resolve with the above alongside existing online resources, you will have to wait for someone else to answer since this is mostly CSS related rather than Salesforce, your question simply happens to be within the context of Salesforce.

Comment: glls - thanks for the response but I think your incorrect with your assessment. I don't want exact code and yes this could be CSS or even something else that I'm looking to implement within a "Salesforce" container. This is a great support forum for code underway and ideas yet to come.

Comment: Please let me know what part of the answer you do not understand